# Laravel Eloquent accessor : modify value by request parameter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to add a prefix in username column which is directly coming from HTTP request. My controller function is like below:

```
    public function myFunc(Request $request){
        $prefix = $request->get("prefix");
        $users = User::all(); //need to change
    }
```

My User Model :

```
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        $full_name = $this->name . ' (' . $this->company_name . ')';
        return $full_name;
    }
```

How can I pass the ***$prefix*** in my accessor?

```
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        $full_name = $prefix."- ".$this->name . ' (' . $this->company_name . ')';
        return $full_name;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In laravel how to pass extra data to mutators and accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690538/in-laravel-how-to-pass-extra-data-to-mutators-and-accessors)

Comment: you can't, you need to use a method if you want to pass parameters

Comment: No in my case $prefix is coming from HTTP request as a request parameter

Comment: @Berto99 can you tell me more please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resolve the request in the accessor. Setting a default string if you string is sent.

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    $request = resolve(Request::class);
    $prefix = $request->get('prefix', '');

    return $prefix."- ".$this->name . ' (' . $this->company_name . ')';
}
```

Comment: I suppose  this is a valid solution, but i would ask myself if this is "correct".. you are creating a useless dependency between the method and the request, so why don't just use a good old normal method?

Comment: I feel like accessor is a core approach in Laravel, accessing properties with methods is an anti pattern imo. This is completely valid and solve his case. If you want to avoid the dependency i would create a service for the prefix calculations, but is overkill for this context.

Comment: You mean creating a class like CalculatePrefixService which will just gives you back `$request->get('prefix') ?? ''"` and so then inject that in the model? if so, yes it's a little bit overkill ahah

Comment: But relevant since it does not make sense for Request and Models to be related. For this question it does and in general Laravel is kinda built to break some of the ruels of more traditional OOP design approaches. But since you have such good ideas about it, why didn't you answer it?

Comment: ahah because the first was just a question, the second a question to check if my understanding of service is correct, because i've never found some resources that explains what a Service is really meant for... someone puts some login, someone uses them for injection and so for testing purpose and so on, so it was something like "may this be the idea of the service you was referring to?" ahah so thank you

Comment: "Services" someone call them actions. Is simply a place to put business logic, so it can easier be reused across classes.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using foreach on the eloquent collection in your controller:

```
public function myFunc(Request $request)
{
    $prefix = $request->get("prefix");
    $users  = User::all(); //need to change
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->full_name = $prefix."- ".$user->full_name;
    }
}
```

or you can do it using request() function in your model:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{    
    return request()->prefix."- ".$this->name . ' (' . $this->company_name . ')';
}
```

But I think it's better using conditional like below:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    if (request()->prefix) {
        return request()->prefix."- ".$this->name.' ('.$this->company_name.')';
    } else {
        return $this->name.' ('.$this->company_name.')';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. this also worked but I accepted mhrn's answer as he gave the correct answer at first. I will upvote your answer as soon as I got 15 points :)...

Answer (score 0):

**Lumen: 5.6.*:**

For future reference in case if anyone is wondering how to resolve the current request from the Service Container in accessor.

```
$requestParameter = app('Illuminate\Http\Request')->get('request_parameter_goes_here');
```