# Laravel - Dynamically add field to model and prevent its save

Tags: laravel

I need to add a field to a model, and this field is not a real column, for example:

```
function calculateDiscount(Order $order)
{
  // some logic
  $order->discount = 20; // It's just an example
  return $order
}
```

The field discount is not a real column to database. I need to add this "dynamic" field to use later.

If I perform a save like:

```
$order->save();
```

I get the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'discount' in 'field list' (SQL: update `orders` set `discount` = 20, where `id` = 67586)
```

There is a way to add a "dynamic" field and prevent Laravel save it ?

Comment: try defining property  public $discount=null; in your model

Comment: It was so simple.. it works! Simply defining the variable prevent laravel to call the macig method __set that add the field to $attribute list. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

use [`appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

**Models/Order.php**

```php
class Order extends Model {
    protected $appends = [
        'discount'
    ];

    public function getDiscountAttribute() {
        // your logic of how to get discount value
        return $discount;
    }
}
```

---

or you can load the `discount` attribute only when you need

```php
// controller
$order->append('discount'); // load the value

// model
class Order extends Model {
    public function getDiscountAttribute() {}
}
// add the getDiscountAttribute function only
```

Comment: Yes! That is the correct answear!

Comment: I can't calculate the discount inside the model, I need to calculate it outside because its depends by other logic (not only the model) :(

Comment: @Mistre83 you means pass extra variables to `getDiscountAttribute()`? Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690538/in-laravel-how-to-pass-extra-data-to-mutators-and-accessors) help?

Comment: Thanks to you all, the reply was given by John solved my problem. i take. are to your all suggestions too